# How to add a dummy row of data in the pivot table so that I can show a nice trendline in my pivot chart?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, trendline, pivot-chart

I have a pivot table that shows the number of bugs and requirements on a particular day and the trendline is portrayed using a pivot chart.

I would like to add another row of data for the next date saying there were 0 bugs. How do I do that?

[image]

I would like to add a row for 19th August saying that there were no bugs or no requirements.
[image]

and then show the trendline dropping to zero

After adding the row and hiding the column in the pivot table. The chart looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Modify your source data?

Comment: I cannot modify it in the required manner. The fields that are populating from the source data is called "TYPE" which can either be a bug or requirement and THE PIVOT TABLE calculates the count of type and displays it. So how do I add a row in the source data when I don;t have a bug or requirement?

Comment: One option is to just add the date `19th August` to your source data and then hide (not filter, just hide) the "blank" column in your pivot table.

Comment: Smart! I did that and it worked but the pivot chart shows the blank legend key as well. I have added the image above.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about the data table. You can delete the "blank" from the legend (if you have one), but not from the table, as far as I know.

Comment: yeah! I meant the table. I don't think I can delete it from the table

Comment: Rather than create the chart from a pivot, can you create from a non-pivot version of the pivot data? For example, Pivot is in columns A, B and C. In cell E2, have a formula for =A2. Repeat for all 3 columns and all rows. Then add a row at the bottom for the next date, and input 0's for bug and requirement fields. Create chart from this data . You can hide the pivot, too.

Comment: I got it. I can just filter and blank is not shown in the table